# Makefile not setting targets based on environment variable value

Tags: makefile

I want to run specific rules if a particular environment variable is set else run the default rules. As an example, I want to run `test1 and test2` if environment variable `MYTARGETS1` is NOT set. However with the below code, always `test1` rule is running when I use `make run` command.

```
MYTARGETS1 ?= True 

ifeq (${MYTARGETS1},True)
MYTARGETS = test1 test2
else
MYTARGETS = test1
endif

test1:
    echo "test1"

test2:
    echo "test2"

run: common $(MYTARGETS)

common:
    echo "common"
```

Comment: Why downvote? This is my requirement, I know one solution could be to use `MYTARGETS` as env and pass the rules to run, but I don't want it that way!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little bug in your code. The first line should be `MYTARGETS1 ?= false` or just `MYTARGETS1 ?=` because `?=` is known as conditional assignment meaning if the variable is not already set, set it with whatever you assign here. With the current changes i suggested if you pass `MYTARGETS1` to `make` then the makefile will work according to your requirement

```
make MYTARGETS1=true
```

Comment: I can only run this makefile as `make run` in my actual code. This is just an example

Comment: Then you better remove the first line itself.